# XmlDsigC14NTransform error during canonicalization when signature exists

Tags: c#, xml, rsa, signature

I’m upgrading our encryption to use 4096-bit RSA when signing an XML document.  The Private data node contains data used by our libraries. There is older data that is used and newer data for our updated libraries.

I’m trying to allow the older libraries to validate the signature using the older 1024-bit key so they can still read the data they need.  And the newer libraries will validate the new signature using the 4096-bit key.  This would allow our older libraries to still validate the document and read the older data they need, while the newer libraries will be able to validate the newer signature then read the data they need.

When signing I do the following:

1. Canonicalize the document
2. Sign with the 4096-bit key and add it to the document.
3. Canonicalize the document
4. Sign with the 1024-bit key and add it to the document.

The XML should look like this when all is working correctly:

```
<Data>
    <PrivateData>
    </PrivateData>
    
    <SignatureV2 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignatureV2Value>---signature---</SignatureV2Value>
    </SignatureV2>
    
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignatureValue>---signature--- </SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
</Data>
```

But when I then try to sign with the 1024-bit key the canonicalization fails. Here is the code:

```
XmlDsigC14NTransform transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform(false);
transform.Resolver = resolver;
transform.LoadInput(xmlDoc);

//get the output
using (MemoryStream mem = (MemoryStream)transform.GetOutput())
{
      //return the output string
      return this.CharacterEncoder.GetString(mem.ToArray());
}
```

I get a System.ArgumentException at XmlDsigC14NTransform.transform.GetOutput() when doing the transform into the memory stream.
System.ArgumentException: 'Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ''  Key being added: '''

After some testing, if I remove the namespace from the SignatureV2 element it works and I end up with:

```
    <Data>
        <PrivateData>
        </PrivateData>
        
        <SignatureV2>
            <SignatureV2Value>---signature---</SignatureV2Value>
        </SignatureV2>
        
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignatureValue>---signature--- </SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
    </Data>
```

Even using just "foo" as the namespace still has the issue.  Only if I remove the namespace attribute altogether does it work.

I'm not sure why it is failing.

Comment: Put the namespace URL into you browser and go the webpage.  The type of encryption is specified in the xml webpage.  You are using a different encryption method so the schema check is failing.

Comment: I'm using RSA with 1024-bit keys for the signature, and RSA with 4096-bit keys for the v2 signature.  Other than key size, I'm using the same encryption method.  I'm able to sign with either size key, I just can't sign with the 4096-bit key then sign with the 1024-bit key.  

I looked through the namespace XML and didn't see anything there that was helpful.  Perhaps it has something to do with the placement of the signatures?  Both would be siblings in the XML.

Comment: I would take the xml file and use one of the online schema check tools and see if the schema find errors.